# Pypy 3.2 Pillow Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

I'm on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I'm trying to use pypy 3.2 to run a django application.

But whenever I try pypy3 manage.py runserver 0:8000, it says:
(fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".

But if I try to install Pillow:
pypy3 -m pip install Pillow

It says:
Requirement already up-to-date: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Pillow-2.9.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg

Then I downloaded the source and tried:
pypy3 setup.py install

And it says:
Attribute error install_layout

I don't know what to do!!

> _<

Answer (score 3):

You should create a proper virtualenv with pypy3 as your interpreter t run your django install -  inside the virtualenv, pip should just work for both django and Pillow - without strange maneuvers like `pypy3 -m pip` which are subject to breakrage like teh one you've got.

To create a virtualenv inside which the default Python interpreter is pypy3 just do `virtualenv -p pypy3 myprojectdir` - and activate it with `source myprojectdir/bin/activate`  - for the lazy types there is `virtualenv wrapper`  which creates even more shortcuts. From there on, `pip install` anything will install thins in this directory, without messing (or checking) your system packages from any other Python.

That is the way to have a sane environment- however it seens you are just trying to be beyond the edge for what is available now - there are mentions on the internet of Pillow being compatible with Pypy (and, of course, with python3) - but I could not find a single mention about running  Pillow with pypy3.

I can get it to build without errors, by installing the `pypy3-devel` on my Linux system, and manually setting the CFLAGS variable - (I am using fedora here - on Ubunut you should have a `pypy3-dev` package). But even though it does build, it does fail to run on pypy, raising `ImportError: unable to load extension module 'PIL/_imaging.pypy3-24.so': PIL/_imaging.pypy3-24.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_SystemError`; (On fedora 22I set `CFLAGS=-I/usr/lib64/pypy3-2.4.0/include/` check your `pypy3-dev` package to see where do these include files are on Ubuntu).

**TL;DR** Either use pypy2.x or regular cPython3.4 (of course this is preferred) for your project - one of these days the dependencies will catch up. Either way Django should not benefit that much from Pypy's JIT - a heavily loaded webserver will have to deal with database connection scalability (not Python) and good caching (which can be properly configured on layers above Python as well - take a look at "varnish"). If you have that much processing on requests that your site is taking a hit for not using Pypy, consider run the bottleneck algorithms in another process using celery/RPCs - and write that part of the program to run with Pypy/Cython/pure C.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: Django is sure taking lots of processing here. But the funny party is I just barely started the website. All I have is a base template and a footer template which does a query and iterate through its content, filling the footer with 'last 4 added products'. It cannot stand 20req/s.

The database processing % is lesser than 0.5%. And it seems a simple page access temporarily takes 10% of processing. This does not happeng to a php page I have doing the same thing, querying the database and then iterating on the webpage showing content.

I'm using nginx with uwsgi.

Comment: Improvements: using caching had magnificent results! Allowing me to have 100+ requests per sec and more!!

But I'm still a bit sad by the amount of processing django is taking. =(